# Use try and except to skip a file

Tags: python, numpy, try-except

I am defining a list of nc files between 2 dates:

```
inlist = ['20180101.nc’, ‘20180102.nc’,  ‘20180103.nc’]
```

Let’s suppose that the file in the middle (‘20180102.nc’) does not exist.

I am trying to use an exception and skip it and continue with the rest, but I can’t manage.

Here’s my code. Note that ncread(i)[0] is a function that reads one variable, which is then concatenated in xap:

```
xap = np.empty([0])
try:
    for i in inlist:
        xap=np.concatenate((xap,ncread(i)[0]))
except IOError as e:
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
    continue
```

This code always stops when it tries to read the file that does not exist (‘20180102.nc’).

How can I skip this file and continue concatenating only the files that exist?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your try/except is placed on the wrong level, you want to try the read, and when it fails continue the loop. This means the try/except must be inside the loop:

```
xap = np.empty([0])
for i in inlist:
    try:
        xap=np.concatenate((xap,ncread(i)[0]))
    except IOError as e:
        print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
        continue
```

Comment: @NickEvangeliou No problem! Please mark answer as accepted :) see link for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

if you also consider another way, here is a simple way to reach your purpose.

#### use this to operate the system

```
import os
```

#### list all your file in current directory(you should change to your object path)

```
filelist=os.listdir("./")

inlist = ['20180101.nc', '20180102.nc',  '20180103.nc']
xap = np.empty([0])
for i in inlist:
   ##** only read the "i" in filelist** 
   if i in filelist: xap=np.concatenate((xap,ncread(i)[0]))
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! I'm downvoting your answer for a reason that: it does not answer the question, it doesn't explain why this solution is good. See also my comment below on @alex3025 answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's another way to do it, it seems, though I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change `IOError` to `FileNotFoundError`:

```
xap = np.empty([0])
try:
    for i in inlist:
        xap=np.concatenate((xap,ncread(i)[0]))
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print "FileNotFoundError({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
    continue
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note the main goal of the community is to share knowledge, not gain points for the activity. When you answer, be sure to check that your code works as intended, that your answer gives the reason of using the approach you insist on, and that your answer is not covered by the others.