# How do I skip a file that gives a ReferenceError in a long list of files that I need to continue to do something with?

Tags: python, try-except, continue, skip

Within a python framework, I am attempting to store several files within the user's working directory that meet certain criteria; these files are created and destroyed by different users at will, so while the storage code is going through the working directory, I am getting a null-pointer "ReferenceError" error, such as the one below when the file still exists but without its histogram attributes (aka are turned into null-pointers):

```
Error in <TFile::TFile>: file ./UL_2022_EE/fits_data/muon/generalTracks/Z/Run2022_EE/tagIsoUp/NUM_HighPtID_DEN_TrackerMuons/NUM_HighPtID_DEN_TrackerMuons_abseta_4_pt_5.root does not exist
ReferenceError: attempt to access a null-pointer
```

(essentially within certain files, nothing is saved that can be accessible to my storage program)

I have attempted many variations of the try-except code, and even an if-then statement that has evolved into something like this:

```
    def catchgeese():
        '''                                                                                                                                                         
        catchgeese() finds the appropriate .png file for the selected fit failure, using pulls or other mathematical parameters, such as the chi2probability distribution, or KS.                                                                                                            
        catchgeese() is used within the 'for' loop to ensure access to TTree 'tests', or any other `VALIDATION parameters` set                                     
        '''
        for i in baseDir:

            try:
                myfile = inFile.replace(".root",".png")
                if not os.path.exists(baseDir + '/geese/'): os.makedirs(baseDir + '/geese/')

            except ReferenceError: 
                print("Failed job encountered. Please run `./tnp_fitter.py [...] -j 16 --recover` in order to retrieve all jobs")
                continue

            target = (baseDir + '/geese/')
            goosechase = shutil.copy(myfile, target+mytitle()+".png")

            return goosechase
```

where `inFile` is just each separate path to the select file, and baseDir is defined as the working directory where this function runs.

I have also tried putting different for loops above the try-except statement due to getting an error that `continue` is not rightly within the loop if `for` is not present, but the for loop has given a similar error (ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero), while not correctly iterating through the list. The problem I think is that `for i in baseDir` doesn't really work because each `inFile` within the baseDir is a retrieved pathway, not an iterative list (I attempted this from the forum on this question: [Use try and except to skip a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53955904/use-try-and-except-to-skip-a-file)). But, because this particular function is only called when certain mathematical criteria are met, within the user's working directory, I'm not sure exactly how to iterate through the list correctly here. I've tried using things like `os.path.exists()` functions to no avail. Any guidance would be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Please tag the question with a language, and what the question is actually about, rather than some words that happen to be in the code.

Comment: This line is incomplete: `target = (baseDir + '/geese/'`

Comment: What is the value of `baseDir`? You never use `i` in the loop. So you're doing the same thing every time through the loop.

Comment: You should never get null pointer errors when calling standard Python functions. Python doesn't expose pointers to user code, so this implies a bug in the implementation.

Comment: The error message mentions `TFile`, which seems to be part of the ROOT toolkit, not a standard part of Python.

Comment: Not clear if this is an indentation error or intended, but the current code returns *inside* of the for loop, so it will always return on the first iteration of the loop that doesn't enter the `except` block.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety this is definitely not intended; would you mind being more specific? I attempted different indentations but nothing ran my code. Thank you for finding that!

Comment: @Phoenyx  In the code you have posted for `catchgeese()`, the last line `return goosechase` should have one less indentation level i.e. `return goosechase` should be lined up with `for i in baseDir`.  Also, as Barmar pointed out, it's not clear what you're actually iterating over with `for i in baseDir` as you don't show where baseDir is defined (is it a string? a pathlib.Path object?) and you don't use `i` at all within the loop.